# Issue with Schema validation

Tags: validation, json.net, schema

the following used to work with earlier Json version.  After updating with the new version it no longer works

```
var referenceSchema = @"
            {
                ""$id"": ""Shared"",
                ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#"",
                ""type"": ""object"",
                ""additionalProperties"": false,
                ""properties"": {
                    ""FirstName"": {
                        ""$id"": ""Shared/FirstName"",
                        ""type"": ""string"",
                        ""minLength"": 1,
                        ""maxLength"": 50,
                        ""required"": true
                    },
                    ""LastName"": {
                        ""id"": ""Shared/LastName"",
                        ""type"": ""string"",
                        ""minLength"": 1,
                        ""maxLength"": 50,
                        ""required"": true
                    }
                }
            }";

            var schemaSource = @"
            {
                ""id"": ""Employee"",
                ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#"",
                ""type"": ""object"",
                ""additionalProperties"": false,
                ""properties"": {
                    ""FirstName"": {
                        ""$ref"": ""Shared/FirstName""
                    },
                    ""MiddleName"": {
                        ""type"": ""string"",
                        ""minLength"": 1,
                        ""maxLength"": 50,
                        ""required"": false
                    },
                    ""LastName"": {
                        ""$ref"": ""Shared/LastName""
                    }
                }
            }";
```

code :

```
var emptyJsonSchemaString = new JSchema().ToString();
 var resolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver(); //<---- This used to be JsonSchemaResolver, it is deprecated, and no longer used, and replaced with JSchemaPreloadedResolver().  

 var referenceSchema = JSchema.Parse(referenceSource, resolver);

var jsonSchema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJsonString, resolver);
```

the above code used to work without any issue, now its not working,  I had replaced the JsonSchemaResolver with JSchemaPreloadedSchema class, I am wondering if that is an issue itself.  or the Json Schema no longer supports this type of reference.